# How to detect sierra with macro in 10.12

Tags: macos

i want to use `#ifdef __MAC_10_12` to detect that the current os version is 10.12, but the header file `Availability.h` doesn't have this define, the highest version for that file is `#define __MAC_10_11_4       101104`

So how can i do this right now?

Comment: you may need to update your Xcode; the desired `__MAC_10_12` macro is available in the latest SDK in _Xcode8 (8A218a)_, but that seems a compiler directive, you may not be able to use it in runtime environment dynamically.

Comment: @holex, thanks, so how can i check the os version dynamically?

Comment: it depends on whether you are using ObjC or Swift.